# Best way to add a char prefix to a char* in C++?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char, memcpy

I need to add a prefix ('X') to the char* (" is cool").

What is the BEST way to do this?

What is the easiest way?

```
char a = 'X';
char* b= " is cool";
```

I need:

```
char* c = "X is cool";
```

So far I tried strcpy-strcat, memcpy;

I'm aware this sounds as a stupid, unresearched question.
What I was wondering is whether there is a way to add the char to the array without turning the char into a string.

Comment: `char* b= " is cool";` is now ill-formed, btw. It should be `char const* b= " is cool";` or `char b[]= " is cool";`.

Comment: strcat is about as easy as it gets.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: What do you define as "best"? Easiest to read/write the code for, runs fastest, takes up the least amount of memory, looks most aesthetically pleasing in some for of "artwork" IOCCC competition?

Comment: @SBI `strcat()` may be easy, but note that the question wants to prepend with `char a = 'X'`, which is not a `[const] char *[const]`, so `strcat()` is not an appropriate solution (at least without some preprocessing...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using C++ standard library instead of C library functions?

```
auto a = 'X';
auto b = std::string{" is cool"};
b = a+b;
```

or short:

```
auto a ='X';
auto b = a+std::string{" is cool"};
```

note that the explicit cast to string is mandatory.

Comment: I believe this is what I was looking for.. Never programmed before in c++, only c, I was not sure if it can handle + concatenation like java, js or other languages.

Comment: you can, except for concatenation of string literals, wich won't work.

Comment: @VladOtrocol Note that `+` concatenation works for `std::string` objects (which you should use in C++), but not for `char*` C-style strings (which you should **avoid** in C++).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use a string instead of char* ?

```
std::string p = " is cool";
std::string x = 'X' + p;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using C++, so for this purpose, don't use `char*` for strings, use `std::string`.

```
std::string str = std::string("X") + std::string(" is cool");
// Or:
std::string str = std::string("X") + " is cool";
// Or:
std::string str = 'X' + std::string(" is cool");
// Or:
std::string str = std::string{" is cool"};
```

That'll work like a charm, it expresses your intentions, it's readable and easy to type. (Subjective, yes, but whatever.)

---

In case you really need to use `char*` though, do note that `char* b = " is cool";` is invalid because you're using a string literal. Consider using `char b[] = " is cool";`. **That** is an array of chars.

You would use [`strcat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) assuring that enough memory is allocated for the **destination** string.

```
char a[32] = "X"; // The size must change based on your needs.
                  // See, this is why people use std::string ;_;
char b[] = " is cool";

// This will concatenate b to a
strcat(a, b);

// a will now be "X is cool"
```

But seriously man, avoid the C-side of C++ and you will be happier and more productive [citation needed].

Comment: "That'll work like a charm, it expresses your intentions, it's readable and easy to type." Nope. It expresses intentions, but won't compile, because addition of two `char const*` is nonsense for the compiler. For the other part of your answer: why first tell him to use C++ and then fall back to unsafe C functions?

Comment: @ArneMertz What I've noticed is that when people don't use STL, they're doing homework or something.

Comment: Well, either he *is* allowed to use STL, then giving him the clean solution is sufficient and shows him something new to learn. Or he is *not* allowed to use it, then he should explicitly say so in the question and we should not encourage him to write sloppy questions ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
char a[20] = "X";
char b[] = " is cool";
strcat(a,b);
```

Comment: this is unsafe wrt string lengths: if you change the string from " is cool" to " is really, really, cool", you get UB.